# Horizontal CSS Menu with Subnav - Set active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I'm using some css menu it's something like this:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/horizontal-subnav/

The only difference is that he uses just simple links as a subnav, I'm using a `<ul class="subnav">` for each topnav tabs.

I've created a css class `.active` and set it's attributes to the same as `#topnav li:hover`

When it's active, I want it to look the same as when it's hovered, also the `subnav` will be visible because both `:hover` and `.active` on the **topnav** items activate the display property of the **subnav**.

The problem is: When I already have a tab with the `.active` class and I hover the other tabs, their child subnavs will also have **display:block**..

I want a solution that doesn't rely entirely on javascript to navigate. But js can be used just for showing what's active, since it's not crucial for navigation..

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, but have a look at Stu Nicholls [huge list of CSS menu examples](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your CSS rules just need to be split up.  So instead of

```
.active, #topnav li:hover { rules here }
```

copy only the properties you want for `.active` and split it:

```
#topnav li:hover { rules here }
.active { subset of rules here }
```